# Ho to upload file to Amazon S3 in node.js from a specific location

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 and the file has in a specific directory.

I tried as follows:

```
  const parsedEndpoint = await parseString(this, endpoint);
  // post it to rest api
  const url = `${this.appUrl}/${parsedEndpoint}?access_token=${this.auth.access_token}`;
  const options = {
    url,
    json: false,
  };
  const filePath = await this.getResourcePath(`/uploads/p.png`);
  options.formData = {
    filename: `p.png`,
    file: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
  };
  this.lastResponse = await rp.postQ(options);
  expect(this.lastResponse.statusCode).to.equal(200);
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to achieve ? Upload to backend server and then upload to S3, or directly from the frontend upload to S3 ? Is it a private bucket ?

Comment: directly upload to S3 @AnkitDeshpande

Comment: private bucket ?